# multiprocessing namespace in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing

def everyM01D000200(ns):

    print(ns.a) # '123c' 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    ns = mgr.Namespace()

    ns.a = '123c'

    print(ns.a)
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=everyM01D000200, args=(ns,))
    p1.start()
```

I expected it to be printed as '123c', but an error occurs.
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] No specified file found.

Perhaps there is a different procedure when taking the variable of namespace from the function.

Comment: Traceback please. Error appears unrelated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your main process is terminating before joining the subprocess, i.e. waiting for it to complete, and the `SyncManager` process that services proxy method calls to any managed objects created, such as the `NameSpace` instance you created, has terminated. The `FileNotFoundError` exception is due to the `multiprocessing.Pipe` used for communication between the proxy object and the `SyncManager` process having been broken (the connection on the `SyncManager` side has been closed).

```py
import multiprocessing

def everyM01D000200(ns):

    print(ns.a) # '123c'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    ns = mgr.Namespace()

    ns.a = '123c'

    print(ns.a)
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=everyM01D000200, args=(ns,))
    p1.start()
    # Wait for subprocess completion:
    p1.join()
```

Prints:

```
123c
123c
```